# Appending whitespace to a variable in AWK script

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I have an AWK script, which receives an input variable from another script.
The length of the input variable is compared. if the length is 3, two whitespace is added infront of variable. If the length is 4, 1 whitespace is added in front. I could compare the length but am not able to append white space.
   **I tried the following in AWK script**

```
if (length(input_variable) ==3 ) {
   input_variable = "  "input_variable
 } else if(length(input_variable) ==4 ){
 input_variable = " "input_variable      
 }print input_variable
```

Output: No value is getting printed. Please help me

Comment: You're mixing the spellings `input_varaible` and `input_variable`. Better stick to the latter.

Comment: No @EdMorton. I want to append whitespace and save it to the same variable

Comment: Yeah. That's my complete script. Is there any other alternate way to perform the same operation as i mentioned above

Comment: You have your parentheses wrong: `if (length(input_variable ==3 ))` needs to be `if (length(input_variable) == 3)` -- most likely, the value of  "input_variable" is not equal to "3", so you have `if (length(0))` which happens to be true.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried this and it worked fine. input_variable="\t"input_variable. i dont want tab space to get appended. based on the length i want to append space.          I did not get any syntax error. Why i'm gonna hide this. I'm new to script. I'd to happy to learn rather than hiding

Comment: @glennjackman yeah i had (length(input_variable) == 3). i mentioned it wrongly. i printed the length, it's coming well and good

Comment: When posting online, always cut and paste, never retype. You wasted my time reporting a problem that doesn't exist and your time telling me about it.

Comment: @EdMorton This is full one. If you could not believe, i'm sry for wasting your time.

Comment: @glennjackman Do you haveany idea why it's not getting printed

Comment: @user5705451 you are showing us just part of a car engine and asking us to believe you drove it to work and asking us to help you diagnose why the indicator is flashing too quickly. The script you posted is simply not a complete awk script and as such awk will not run it but will instead report a syntax error when you try to execute it and we cannot help you diagnose a problem that is outside of that segment of code that you have shown us so far.

Comment: i have no idea of what you're looking for. Rather than arguing, i ll look up with someone. Thank you for your help

Comment: I suggest you put in some more effort to work with the SO community. Read [ask] and [mcve], and the edit your question with some sample input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `printf`

```
awk '{printf "%5s", $1}'
```

pads with spaces on the left to the desired length, don't reinvent.

Comment: i'd like to append whitespace and save it to the same variable. I dont want to print it directly. By the way what does $1 means in your statement

Comment: @EdMortonThanks for your valuable time. Better ans from others would be helpful

Comment: okay i ll wait for others. i ll let you know if i could find ans from anyone

Comment: Since you haven't found an answer to any of your previous questions (except one you chose which as it turns out is actually a dangerously wrong answer), you may want to consider the possibility that the problem is the way you ask questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Fine. i ll look at it.